# Does $L(\lambda)$ must be an irreducible direct summand of $V$?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Suppose $L$ is a finite dimensional simple Lie algebra, $V$ is finite dimensional $L$-module.

If $\lambda$ is the highest weight of $V$, does $L(\lambda)$ must be an irreducible direct summand of $V$?

I have no idea, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you working over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: And the definition of $L(\lambda)$ is ... ? (I suspect that tells you already it is irreducible, so you only ask if it occurs as direct summand.) And have you learned already that $V$ is completely reducible? (Because then you only have to check if it has submodule isomorphic to $L(\lambda)$.)

Comment: @Dylan over an algebraically closed field F of characterisitic 0.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I know $L(\lambda)$ is isomorphic to a submodule of $V$ by using Verma module when V is the highest weight module. But here V just a module with the highest weight $\lambda$, is V a highest weight module?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg And why do I just have to prove that it's a submodule, is there exist a submodule $W$, such that $V=L(\lambda) \oplus W$?

Comment: You have not answered either of my questions really ...

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Sorry. $L(\lambda)$ is the unique irreducible quotient of $M(\lambda)$. By Weyl's theorem, $V$ is completely reducible.

Comment: Aha, good. So $L(\lambda)$ is irreducible by definition, and the fact that $V$ is completely reducible answers your last question to me affirmatively. So, as said, you only have to show $L(\lambda)$ is a submodule of $V$. --- By the way, what does it mean that $\lambda$ is the highest weight of $V$? And, knowing $V$ is completely reducible, what could its irreducible summands be? Are they not all highest weight modules for certain weights? What weights could that be, compared to $\lambda$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg According to "Lie Algebra of Finite and Affine Type", $\lambda$ is the highest weight of V if $\lambda \succ \mu$ for all weights $\mu$ of V. And is it right that because $V$ is completely reducible, so it can be decomposed into some irreducible finite dimensional module, so each of them is isomorphic to one of $L(\mu)$, and assume we know $L(\lambda)$ is a submodule, so it must be one of them.

Comment: You don't need to assume $L(\lambda)$ is a submodule. We can see that it must be because none of the other $L(\mu)$ can contain a $\lambda$ weight space (or $\lambda \succ \mu$ would be violated)

Comment: @Callum Yes, you are right. Thanks.